# css, flex-direction, sticky element

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky

I'm working with flex and two modes to change the flex-direction:

```
@mixin for-medium-up {
@media (min-width: 670px) { @content; }
}
@mixin for-large-up {
@media (min-width: 880px) { @content; }
}
```

In the first mode (min-width: 880px), I want to have a sticky element on the right-hand side as follows:

[image]

the sticky element is defined as follows:

```
.sticky {
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: -moz-sticky;
position: -ms-sticky;
position: -o-sticky;
position: sticky;
}
```

In the second mode (min-width: 670px), I want to have it as follows:

[image]

where the sticky element is sticky in the first mode, it does not stick in the second one.

here is the [Demo](https://codepen.io/Anathapindika/pen/BmgyON)

Comment: Put position sticky on your container of the current sticky element for the second view https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position it is sticky relative to its parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer isn't quite as simple as attaching something to the parent element.

I've modified your demo and made some simplifications for clarity but I believe it achieves your intended goal.

[Modified Demo](https://codepen.io/NDfool/pen/zPVbVB)

Consider the case where the elements are side-by-side...

The default value of `align-items` for flex box items is `stretch` (see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)). This means that the `.view` element grows in size to fill the full height, meaning that it never has the opportunity to become "stuck". This can be addressed by using `align-self: flex start` or by explicity setting the height, e.g. `height: 100px`.

If you un-comment line 10 and comment-out line 11, you'll see the issue.

Hope this helps.